# Scrollbar dissapeared in IE11. Is there any CSS rule for avoiding that?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm aware of the other posts asking about the same as I am, but none of the options fits wiht my situation.

I have a web application, that works ok with different browsers, including IE (8).

- O.S: Windows 7

When customers changed to IE11, scrollbars, on SELECT, and TEXTAREA elements (maybe other elements too) disappears. As you can see on the image, it seems that scrollbar is there but transparent.

I have tried every compatibility stuff I have found googling. 
I have tried with a stylesheet (filled with `-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}`) 
at Internet options>general>accesibility...

We have the following style rules added to body:

```
body {
    color: #383838;
    background-position: 0px;
    scrollbar-face-color: #910046;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @downvoters, maybe a reason for the downvote? it seems that you think that this question is not about programming?

Comment: I did not vote down, but perhaps you can list which other solutions you have discarded?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, i have tried with all the solutions i have found on microsoft support page. It talks about modifiying options of compatibility view, talks about adding a stylesheet... i have tried moving the attributes scrollbar.. to the element itself... but no results. im just wondering if anyone has the Coding solution for this, or any other idea for start trying. Thanks

Comment: Post a link where we can reproduce the problem. Also get rid of the scrollbar styling.

Comment: As soon as i go back to the office i will try to. I have been trying everything i know about scrollbar styling, and things i dont know too

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfx2vnt5/) that shows scrollbars for me in IE11 on Windows 7.

Comment: @AndréDion, thanks for the effort, i can see that scroollbar too... im starting to get crazy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fired up my IE11 machine, and what shows: Your arrows are white on white. They take up space. Making the textarea higher shows the scrollbar between them. This is behaviour as expected.

This will make the arrows visible:

```
body {
    color: #383838;
    background-position: 0px;
    scrollbar-face-color: #910046;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #910046;
}
```

And here is the proof (with a higher textarea): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyqVag?editors=1100

Here is IE11:

[image]

Here is IE8:

[image]

It seems like IE11 does not have a '(sur)face' behind the arrows, while IE8 has. Therefore `scrollbar-face-color: #910046;` does not work to create contrast on the arrows in IE11. This is supported by this article from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531157(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks. I know that is strange,  the white over white stuff. But it works on IE8, so my question is just that: why? do i need to add something else anywehere to make it work with IE11?

Comment: it seems that the colors of the scrollbar attributes shows at least a path to follow. but it is still strange situation

Comment: The arrows take up more space in IE11 than before. That is why.

Comment: thanks i will try with this suggestion. If it works i will let you all know.

Comment: A suggestion for a cross browser solution for fancy scrollbars: http://iscrolljs.com.

Comment: solution to my question is ok, even it doesnt explain me how and why this code works on IE8. I will come back with a new question when i advance some steps more.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more background info and extra screenshots.

Comment: thanks! Really helpfull that analyse! I will read that info carefully and give some messages and optioms to PManagers and customer!